# Order By in List<T> with Lambda Expression when foreign key is null

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Below is my query:

```
List<db_table> listData = db.db_table.Take(50).ToList();
```

Now I want this list as sorted list. For that I tried:

```
listData = db.db_table.OrderBy(x => x.db_table1.column_name).ToList();
```

My column contains 'null' also at that time it throws an error.

Consider that db_table has foreign key assigned from db_table1

Comment: Do you want null values filtered out?  If not, where do you want them in the sorted list?

Comment: I want to filtered out that also. For me, it is necessary to get in list.

Comment: So put `.Where(x => x.db_table1 != null)` before the `OrderBy`.

Comment: @DStanley Let me try that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend your lambda expression or using [c# 6 features](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#null-conditional-operators):

```
// use c# 6.0 ?. operator
listData = db.db_table
             .OrderBy(x => x.db_table1?.column_name)
             .ToList();

// check value manually
listData = db.db_table
             .OrderBy(x => x.db_table1 != null ? x.db_table1.column_name : string.Empty)
             .ToList();

// filter null values before sorting
listData = db.db_table
             .Where(x => x.db_table1 != null)
             .OrderBy(x => x.db_table1.column_name)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: You could probably do this for your first query: `.OrderBy(x => x.db_table1?.column_name ?? "")`

Comment: @vadim I've tried second options from your answer and worked for me. Thanks man!!!

Comment: @vadim after applying the options you posted above here, item count in the list is decreased.

Comment: @Ranger I'm not sure what are you asking. If you are using second options without `Where` method then the count of items can't be decreased.

Comment: @VadimMartynov sorry.. it was a bug, not a code issue...code is working fine for me.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `Where` clause before the `OrderBy`:

```
listData = db.db_table
             .Where(x => x.db_table1 != null)
             .OrderBy(x => x.db_table1.column_name)
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
listData = db.db_table.OrderBy(x => x.db_table1?.column_name ?? "").ToList();
```