# C#, LINQ a generic sort method to sort a list by object properties and nested properties

Tags: linq, sorting, dynamic-queries, nested-properties

I have an entity called User in my EF Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Branch HomeLocation{ get; set; }   
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserCode { get; set; }
}
```

Branch is another entity in the model:

```
public class Branch
{    
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public string BranchName{ get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; } 
}
```

My requirement is to get a users list and display it on a grid, and then sort the list by some of the columns (one at a time). Say, for example, sort by username, firstname, lastname and HomeLocation. When sorting by homelocation, it should be sorted by the branch name.

I have many grids like this displaying other data as well. So I want to develop a generic sort mechanism and I have achieved it using some of the examples found in Google, for example [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37541/Generic-Sorting-with-LINQ-and-Lambda-Expressions):

```
public class GenericSorter<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable<T> source, string sortBy, string sortDirection)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");

        var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>
            (Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, sortBy), typeof(object)), param);

        switch (sortDirection.ToLower())
        {
            case "asc":
                return source.AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy<T, object>(sortExpression);
            default:
                return source.AsQueryable<T>().OrderByDescending<T, object>(sortExpression);

        } 
    }
}
```

However, sorting by home location fails because it needs to be sorted by an inner property of the user entity. I've tried using [Dynamic LINQ library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) too, but there's no luck.

Update: Note that I have to sort a List, not IQueryable, because my list contains fields encrypted with AE, which don't support DB-level sorting.

Can someone point out to me how to achieve the dynamic sorting from an inner property?

Update2: I followed the example and implemented the sort using the extension methods and this is how it's applied on my list:

```
var users = (from u in context.Users.Include("Branch")
                    where (u.FkBranchId == branchId || branchId == -1) && u.IsActive
                        && (searchTerm == string.Empty || (u.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm) || u.LastName.Equals(searchTerm)
                            || u.UserName.Contains(searchTerm) || u.UserCode.Contains(searchTerm)))
                    select u).ToList();

        var rowCount = users.Count;

        var orderedList = users.OrderBy(sortInfo.SortColumn).Skip(pageInfo.Skip).Take(pageInfo.PageSize).ToList();
```

But I get the following error:
Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ClientData.User,System.String]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Func`2[ClientData.User,System.String]'.

Error is thrown from the following:

```
object result = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(
                method => method.Name == methodName
                        && method.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                        && method.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2
                        && method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), type)
                .Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda });
```

After this, I'm receiving the following error, in some occasions as explained in the comment:
[image]

Comment: Why do this in Linq, let the grid handle the sorting for you?

Comment: Well, this is a legacy application using ASP.NET GridView and we are sort of re-writing with minimal changes to the existing implementation

Comment: Have you already checked this one ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/3470596

Comment: Nope, I will try that out, thanks.

Comment: @dbraillon: so there's a limitation in using that. In the said post, the sorting is done on IQueryable, which doesn't work for me, because I have sort fields encrypted with AE which doesn't support DB level sorting. So I have to first convert them to a List and then sort - using a generic sort.

Comment: If I understood you well, just change Queryable by Enumerable in the code and you should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapt the code from @MarcGravell found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/3470596).

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        string property)
    {
        return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "OrderBy");
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        string property)
    {
        return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "OrderByDescending");
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> ThenBy<T>(
        this IOrderedEnumerable<T> source,
        string property)
    {
        return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "ThenBy");
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> ThenByDescending<T>(
        this IOrderedEnumerable<T> source,
        string property)
    {
        return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "ThenByDescending");
    }

    static IOrderedEnumerable<T> ApplyOrder<T>(
        IEnumerable<T> source,
        string property,
        string methodName)
    {
        string[] props = property.Split('.');
        Type type = typeof(T);
        ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        Expression expr = arg;
        foreach (string prop in props)
        {
            // use reflection (not ComponentModel) to mirror LINQ
            PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop);
            expr = Expression.Property(expr, pi);
            type = pi.PropertyType;
        }
        Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), type);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, expr, arg);

        object result = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(
                method => method.Name == methodName
                        && method.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                        && method.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2
                        && method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), type)
                .Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda.Compile() });
        return (IOrderedEnumerable<T>)result;
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

Use it from a List<> :

```
var list = new List<MyModel>();
list = list.OrderBy("MyProperty");
```

Comment: How do I access this OrderBy outside of the implementation class? In that example, the implementation is in Program class, and accessed within the Main() method.

Comment: Put it in an extension class, please see my updated answer

Comment: I updated the question with another error I get after applying the given solution.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's because it is encapsulated inside an Expression, try to compile it.
`.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda.Compile() });`, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's good so far, but I'm getting a null reference exception in certain instances, for example - when a sort column has empty or null values. The source of the error is 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. The screenshot attached in the original thread.

Comment: Is there anyway I can still sort with say user.Branch.BranchName, when for some users Branch would be null? I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927146/order-by-in-listt-with-lambda-expression-when-foreign-key-is-null, but not sure how to apply it.

Comment: You should take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17650708/3470596 that is exactly what you need